# Javascript Regexp Duplicate Line Matching not working correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, duplicates

I am writing a Javascript code to parse some grammar files, it is quite some code but I will post relevant information here.  I am using Javascript Regexp in order to match a duplicate line held within a string.  The string contains, for example (assume the string name is lines):

```
    if
    else
    ;
    print
    {
    }
    test1
    test1
    =
    +
    -
    *
    /
    (
    )
    num
    string
    comment
    id
    test2
    test2
```

What should happen, is a match found on 'test1' and 'test2'.  It should then delete the duplicate, leaving 1 instance of test1 and test2.  What is happening is no match at all.  I am confident in my regex but javascript may be doing something I am not expecting.  Here is the code doing the work on the string given above:

```
var rex = new RegExp("(.*)(\r?\n\1)+","g");
var re = '/(.*)(\r?\n\1)+/g';

rex.lastIndex = 0;


var m = rex.exec(lines);
    if (m) {
        alert("Found Duplicate");
        var linenum = lines.search(re);            //Get line number of error
        alert("Error: Symbol Defined twice\n");
        alert("Error occured on line: " + linenum);
        lines = lines.replace(rex,"");         //Gets rid of the duplicate
    }
```

It never gets into the if(m) statement.  Therefore no match is found.  I tested the regex here: http://regexpal.com/  using the regex in my code as well as the example text provided.  It matches just fine, so I am at kind of a loss.  If anyone can help, it would be great.

Thank you.

Edit:
Forgot to add, I am testing this in firefox, and it only has to work in firefox.  Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'if\nelse\n;\nprint\n{\n}\ntest1\ntest1\n=\n+\n-\n*\n/\n(\n)\nnum\nstring\ncomment\nid\ntest2\ntest2\ntest2\ntest2\ntest2';
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(/\r\n?/g,'');
// I prefer replacing all the newline characters with \n's here
str = str.replace(/(^|\n)([^\n]*)(\n\2)+/g,function(m0,m1,m2,m3,ind) {
    var line = str.substr(0,ind).split(/\n/).length + 1;
    var msg = '[Found duplicate]';
    msg += '\nFollowing symbol defined more than once';
    msg += '\n\tsymbol: ' + m2;
    msg += '\n\ton line ' + line;
    console.log(msg);
    return m1 + m2;
});
console.log(str);
```

Otherwise you can skip the first line and change the pattern into

```
/(^|\r\n?|\n)([^\r\n]*)((?:\r\n?|\n)\2)+/g
```

Note that `[^\n]*` will also catch multiple empty lines. If you want to make sure it matches (and replaces) non-empty lines then you might want to use `[^\n]+`.

**[EDIT]**

For the record, each `m` represents each `arguments` object, so `m0` is the whole match, `m1` is the 1st subgroup (`(^|\n)`), `m2` is the 2nd subgroup (`([^\n]*)`) and `m3` is the last subgroup (`(\n\2)`). I could have used `arguments[n]` instead but these are shorter.

As with the return value, due to lack of lookbehind in the regex flavor used by Javascript, this pattern is catching a possible preceding newline (unless it is the first line) so it needs to return the match and that preceding newline if any. That's why it shouldn't be returning `m2` only.

Comment: What is the function of m0,m1,m3?  The function returns m1+m2 but what value will this hold? I don't see m1 used anywhere.

Comment: @Dohrann I added that explanation in my answer for all to see what's happening with those arguments.

Comment: I understand now, thank you, although this matches at line '18 and line 20'.  So it matches the first 'test2' and the 'empty' whitespace afterwards.  This i don't understand.  Also, the replace does not replace correctly, the string still returns what it had before.

Comment: @Dohrann The code I provided finds consecutive **identical** lines and eliminates all after the last one, and it's written based on your question and comments you posted to the previous answer. If this was not what you asked, you will need to edit your question.

Comment: @Dohrann I forgot the `str =` part before `str.replace(...)`. Sorry about that. It works in all the browsers I tried btw.

Answer (score 0):

**First error**: `\` in a JS string is also an escape character.

```
var rex = new RegExp("(.*)(\r?\n\1)+","g");
```

should be written

```
var rex = new RegExp("(.*)(\\r?\\n\\1)+","g");
// or, shorter:
var rex = /(.*)(\r?\n\1)+/g;
```

if you want to make it work.  In the case of the `RegExp` constructor, you’re passing the pattern as a string to the constructor function. This means you need to escape each `\` backslash that occurs in the pattern.  If you use a regexp literal, you don’t need to escape them, since they’re not in a string, but retain their ‘normal’ properties in the regexp pattern.

**Second error**, your expression

```
var re = '/(.*)(\r?\n\1)+/g';
```

is wrong. What you’re doing here is assigning a **string** literal to a variable. I’m assuming you meant to assign a **regular expression** literal, which should be written like this:

```
var re = /(.*)(\r?\n\1)+/g;
```

**Third error**: the last line

```
lines = lines.replace(rex,"");         //Gets rid of the duplicate
```

removes *both instances* of *all* duplicate lines!  If you want to keep the first instance of each duplicate, you should use

```
lines = lines.replace(rex, "$1");
```

---

And finally, this method only detects two *consecutive* identical lines. Is that what you want, or do you need to detect *any* duplicates, wherever they may be?

Comment: Yes it only needs to detect consecutive identical lines.  I remember changing var re=//g to var re='//g' but I'm not sure why, that's a duh mistake.  With the escape characters I did not even think about the fact it was a string and that I had to escape them.  Thanks for the reply, I'll update if I get it working.